# MySQL Join with where and group query

Tags: mysql

I'm currently displaying **total order value** and **quantity of orders** grouped by the date the orders were marked as despatched, with a limit of 5. This data is from my 'orders' table.

```
SELECT COUNT(orders_id) AS order_qty,
DATE_FORMAT(last_modified, "%a %D %b") AS day,                   
SUM(order_total) AS daily_total
FROM orders
WHERE orders_status = 3
GROUP BY DATE(last_modified)
ORDER BY DATE(last_modified) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Result example:

- Mon 21st Aug: £200.12(10 Orders)
- Thu 17th Aug: £210.34 (11 Orders)
- Tue 15th Aug: £220.56 (12 Orders)
- Mon 14th Aug: £230.78 (13 Orders)
- Wed 9th Aug: £240.99 (14 Orders)

I would like to include the total quantity of items that are contained in these orders. This data is stored in my 'orders_products' table. In this table I have a column called **products_quantity** that I need to SUM if the order number is contained in the original query.

I understand I need to use a join, but don't know how to write my query to group the result if the **orders_status** from my **orders** table **= 3** and then group by despatch date?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] by providing some lines of "create table ..." and some sample input in the shape of "insert ...". Show how you desire the result to look like, keeping in mind that you want to show an aggregate of all the lines you have shown. I.e. "mock" the output you want. maybe an additional line at the end which just shows the total. Or maybe I have completely misunderstood, in that case please explain more.

Answer (score 0):

Join the order_products table against the order table and sum them directly.

This may work, I am guessing the field names in order_products:

```
SELECT COUNT(orders_id) AS order_qty,
DATE_FORMAT(last_modified, "%a %D %b") AS day,                   
SUM(order_total) AS daily_total,
SUM(order_products.products_quantity) as total_items
FROM orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_products on order_products.orders_id=orders.orders_id
WHERE orders_status = 3
GROUP BY DATE(last_modified)
ORDER BY DATE(last_modified) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

The joined records will be grouped according to the GROUP BY clause of the joined table, and the values summed accordingly.